# 'ESC' key in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am automating a JS process running on a web page. If I click 'ESC key', my main page loads. I am trying to automate using Robot Framework and Python. I checked Press Key   \27 but its not working. Can someone please point me how to handle it.

Comment: Did you press and release it?

Comment: Yes, manually if I press and release 'ESC' key, it works. I am trying to find the equivalent python statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584937/how-to-detect-key-release-with-python-not-keypress

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but no luck.

Comment: "I am automating a JS process running on a web page. If I click 'ESC key', my main page loads. I am trying to automate using Robot Framework and Python. I checked Press Key \27 but its not working. Can someone please point me how to handle it." To above sentence, even I am facing same issue.
Can you please help me to resolve this? I tried your resolutions but didn't work for me. I am using Selenium2library.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SeleniumLibrary with Robot framework, then you use the `Press Keys` keyword for send ESC key on the currently active browser. 
If you use the excel format editor, then

```
Press Keys | None | ESC
```

OR if you are using the Text editor, then

```
Press Keys    None    ESC
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

This video explains Press Keys keyword for all keys, https://youtu.be/hxQr_zuIhDw